# Application does not launch in admin mode created from visual studio installer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, windows-installer

I have created setup.exe and msi for that, using visual studio 2013 installer project. Setup.exe installs perfectly fine however my application created in program file(X86) will not launch in admin mode by default. Is there any setting i need to do in installer project.

**update:** My .msi runs in admin mode i have added launch condition for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a app.manifest in your project and change the following line in app.manifest file:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Comment: Created Manifest as you said and registered with mt.exe worked for me thank you!!

Comment: just to add..you can do it by editing registry as well>> http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/66259/Requesting-Admin-Approval-at-Application-Start